# POM for Maven Compiler Plugin Jar is missing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

**EDIT**: I've just updated my Eclipse installation from Kepler to Luna - all of my Maven projects were running fine before the update

I am receiving the error which is preventing my Maven project from installing:

```
The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.5.1 is missing, no dependency information available
```

And when I navigate to Maven's Lifecycle Mapping in Eclipse I see

```
compiler:compile      | error
compiler:text Compile | error
```

I have maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1 (including the POM file) in my .m2 repository and would like to use that instead.

How could this be configured in Eclipse? Alternatively, if this is not the solution to the problem, how could this be resolved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to edit your pom.xml to set the version of the compiler plugin to be used. As described on the [plugin's homepage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/usage.html), you configure the maven-compiler-plugin in the `build`-section of your project's pom.xml like so:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <!-- put your configurations here -->
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

If you want to use the local repository of your Maven installation (instead of Eclipse's embedded version), go to Preferences -> Maven -> Installations and add your Maven installation there.

Comment: The joke is that in Luna the embedded Maven runtime will still be used to resolve dependencies even if you configure your own Maven runtime. I had to override the settings.xml myself rather than install my own runtime.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know that. But then again, I'd expect the embedded runtime to download artifacts unavailable in the local repository by itself. Explicitly setting the version of the maven-compiler-plugin in the pom should actually fix the OP's problem (I'd hope so at least).

Comment: If you don't specify a version yourself Maven will use the latest version of the plugin. Since apparently version 2.5.1 is used here, I'd also guess the version is hardcoded in a pom somewhere. Perhaps it is so old it is incompatible with Maven 3.

Comment: @RolandKrüger thank you this resolved my problem. Unfortunately I have have new one: 'Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'myProject'.
org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFilteringException' - Any ideas?

Comment: @ClayBanks: there seems to be a problem with the filtering of the project resources. Without knowing your pom.xml, I can't help you here I'm afraid. Is there some more info about this error, some stacktrace or anything?

Comment: statcktrace: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFilteringException
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) --- The only thing in my POM so far is the junit dependency and now the compiler plugin. My runtime is set to jdk-1.7 and I've added tools.jar as an extra library. I've not had this issue in Kepler

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your setup, since its the MavenFilteringException class that can't be found. But without knowing your setup, I could only guess.